# String split method will not return two strings

Tags: java, string, split

Why does the split method not return an array with 2 elements?

```
for(int i = 0; i < temparray.size(); i++)
{
if (temparray.get(i).contains("_"))
    System.out.println("True" + temparray.get(i).length() + " " + temparray.get(i));
String[] temp = temparray.get(i).split("_");
System.out.println(temp[0]);
//System.out.println(temp[1]);
//friendsOld.add(new Friend(temp[0],temp[1]));
}
```

If I uncomment either of the lines, I get `ArrayOutofBoundsException: 1`. The println always returns True, the length of the String, and then a String with `_` located within the String - NOT at the end.

I've tried negative parameters for `.split()`, converting the String to char arrays and breaking the String using `indexOf()` to find the location of `_` then splitting it manually using `substring()`. There might be something wrong with the String itself but here is the code for the array of Strings: `ArrayList<String> temparray = new ArrayList<String>();`.

Comment: what is the exact string value stored in temparray.get(i)?

Comment: What String are you applying that code to? Show us some examples so it'll be easier to help you find a solution.

Comment: As others mentioned it already: you might have forgot some braces. But also be aware of that trailing empty strings are not included, so the string "foo_" would also return only one element even though it contains your seperator (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Here are examples: 

Yarko Berlinh_40656411
Joseph Nguyen_52233247
Johan Cheah_72681788
@AmitBhargava

Comment: @JoachimRohde, the `_` is never at the end so the trailing string isn't empty. Correct?

Comment: Add an else `S.o.println("FALSE " + temparray.get(i))`. Watch strings without underscores magically appear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you forgot the braces after the if-statement:

```
if (temparray.get(i).contains("_")) {
    System.out.println("True" + temparray.get(i).length() + " " + temparray.get(i));
    String[] temp = temparray.get(i).split("_");
    System.out.println(temp[0]);
    System.out.println(temp[1]);
    friendsOld.add(new Friend(temp[0],temp[1]));
}
```

The way you wrote it, the string is splitted even when it doesn't contain an underscore. Only the output of "True [...]" is limited to strings containing one.

You should start using the debugger - it will display the values of variables when hitting an exception breakpoint allowing you to further track down the bugs in your code.

Comment: I didn't intend for it to have braces. The if-statement was simply meant to make sure that the String was valid for "splitting". Each element of `temparray` returns True for the `contains()`.

Comment: Are you really sure that every element contains and underscore (not only the ones you are printing to the console)? On which element does the exception occur?

Comment: Your comment made me realize something and upon adding another `inStream.readLine();` it worked correctly. I was reading the wrong line first, one off. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean to put all of that code in braces?

```
for(int i = 0; i < temparray.size(); i++)
{
    if (temparray.get(i).contains("_")) {
        System.out.println("True" + temparray.get(i).length() + " " + temparray.get(i));
        String[] temp = temparray.get(i).split("_");
        System.out.println(temp[0]);
        //System.out.println(temp[1]);
        //friendsOld.add(new Friend(temp[0],temp[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't intend for it to have braces. The if-statement was simply meant to make sure that the String was valid for "splitting". Each element of `temparray` returns True for the `contains()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your if condition only applies to the next line. Therefore, if the temparray.get(i) does not contain a '_', you only get a single result from split.